# Is it possible to define the AWS Role you want to use in the zappa_settings.json file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa

When deploying a Python Flask app to AWS Lambda using Zappa

I would rather do it this way than have a Zappa role automatically created for me which I have to modify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a specific role that you already have created in AWS, this can be done by adding the following to your `zappa_settings.json` file.

```
{
"myenvironment": {
    ...
    "manage_roles": false, // Disable Zappa client managing roles.
    "role_name": "MyLambdaRole", // Name of your Zappa execution role. Optional, default: <project_name>-<env>-ZappaExecutionRole.
    "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::12345:role/app-ZappaLambdaExecutionRole", // ARN of your Zappa execution role. Optional.
    ...
},
...
```

}

where you can define the name of the role or its ARN. I would prefer to use the role's ARN.

You can read more about it in Zappa's official documentation [Read here](https://github.com/zappa/Zappa#using-custom-aws-iam-roles-and-policies),
you can also find out what are the minimum permissions Zappa needs to work in the following discussion [Read here](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/244)